# Remplazar carácter especial de un string con php

Tags: php, string

Necesito reemplazar de una cadena un "\" por un "/" he tratado con

```
remove_sp_chr
str_replace
preg_replace
```

y no logro el  objetivo.
está es la cadena

facturas\facturado/FA_0004-00000000.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo fácilmente con **str_replace** así:

```
$str = 'facturas\facturado/FA_0004-00000000.pdf';

echo $str = str_replace("\\", '/', $str);

// facturas/facturado/FA_0004-00000000.pdf
```

Debes poner doble barra **\ \**

Si te funciona recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: Perdón si funciona el problema mío estaba primero comillas dobles, luegos simples, gracias @ochoa

Comment: Seguro @OcielGarrido? es que yo seguí una convención en el script pero funciona con comillas simples en ambos lados también. Pueda que haya sido la doble barra. Me alegra que te funcionara.